# Laravel: Has many through not respecting whereHas

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am trying to construct a `hasManyThrough` relationship in Laravel 10.

I have 3 tables: `users` table (standard Laravel columns), `client_assignments`, and `media_ad_plans`

A user can be assigned to multiple clients in the `client_assignments` table. In the `media_ad_plans` table an entry belongs to one client.

In my `Users` model I am defining the relationship like so:

```
public function adPlans(): HasManyThrough
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        AdPlan::class,
        ClientAssignment::class,
        'user_id',
        'client_id',
        'id',
        'client_id'
    );
}
```

However, when doing something like:

```
    $users = User::with('adPlans.client')->whereHas('adPlans', function ($query) {
        return $query->duringTodayUsing('material_deadline', false); // a custom scope
    })->get();
```

All of the ad plan items associated with a user are returned, not just the one's that match the `whereHas` statement. I've tried a simple query within the `whereHas` closure but it does not change the output - I still get all items for the user. I suspect my relationship is malformed or perhaps I am doing something "illegal." I am not getting any errors.

Client Assignments:

[image]

Ad Plan (useful fields per the question):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`->whereHas()` has no effect on a separate `->with()` clause. Your code is working exactly as expected; `whereHas()` is filtering which `User` records are returned, based on `'adPlans', function ($query) { ... })`, but `->with('adPlans.client')` is correctly returning **ALL** of each `User`'s associated `adPlans` Records.

You either need to duplicate your logic onto your `->with()` clause, like:

```php
$users = User::with(['adPlans' => function ($query) {
  return $query->with('client')->duringTodayUsing('material_deadline', false);
}])->whereHas('adPlans', function ($query) {
  return $query->duringTodayUsing('material_deadline', false);
})->get();
```

Or use Laravel's `->withWhereHas()` Clause:

```php
$users = User::withWhereHas('adPlans', function ($query) {
  return $query->with('client')->duringTodayUsing('material_deadline', false);
})->get();
```

Documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads-with-relationship-existence

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I was batting my head against the wall on this one.

Comment: No problem! I remember the first time I ran into this, and I too couldn't figure out what was going on  Back then, you actually **had** to use separate clauses, so for the longest time, I'd recommend doing `$closure = function ($query) { ... }`, then `->with(['adPlans' => $closure])->whereHas('adPlans', $closure)` to avoid having to write it twice, but since Laravel `9.x`, this `->withWhereHas()` was made available, and it's so much nicer. But I digress; happy I could help! 